# Asp.Net Web Forms access user custom properties on master page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, asp.net-identity

How can I access custom user properties(eg. first name, last name) on the master page if the Web Forms Project is using **Asp.Net Identity System**? I've already made this configurations http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html but my project is not MVC is Web Forms.

By default I can only access user's name using:

```
Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User` should work in master page.

Comment: You cannot access custom properties via HttpContext.Current.User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've found the answer.

On Site.Master.cs add this lines:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using EvSiProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Then add this lines on the Page_Load() function:

```
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        //string fName = currentUser.FirstName;
        //string lName = currentUser.LastName;
    }
```

And that's it.

Comment: Could anyone please provide the front end code if  I want to display 

string fName = currentUser.FirstName; on the site.master

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents to Ceparu's answer:

In Site.Master.cs I also added a public field

```
public ApplicationUser CurrentUser;
```

In the Page_Load() function changed the second line to use the public field

```
CurrentUser = manager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

After changing Site.Master.cs, in Site.Master you can use

```
<%: CurrentUser.FirstName %>
```

Instead of

```
<%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>
```

Done!