# Asp.net Front display custom properties identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I've been trying to displaying custom user properties using asp.net Identity System. Right now I've been following [This tutorial](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html) and also refering to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740713/asp-net-web-forms-access-user-custom-properties-on-master-page). Please be informed that I am very new to ASP.NET webform  coding.

My problem is that i have to idea what is the code that i should use at the master page.

The codes being given in the tutorial are

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using EvSiProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

and

```
if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        //string fName = currentUser.FirstName;
        //string lName = currentUser.LastName;
    }
```

that is going to be used at the back Site.Master.cs.

My question is what is the code that I should use at the Site.Master to display the custom property. The custom property is stored as Address in my databse.

Thank You

Comment: are you wanting to display in a label the `Address` if so then you need to add a label in the master page give it an `ID` and a `runat=server`  and from there you need to add some additional code to gain access to the masterpages label from another page can you show your aspx easiest way to store the value would be in a something like this 
`lblAddress.Text = String.Format("Welcome {0}", HttpContext.Current.Session["Address"].ToString());` of course assigning the `session variable = to , HttpContext.Current.Session["Address"] =currentUser.Address`

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you for your response, but i still do not know how to display the addres that belongs to the user. RIght now, my back code is like this if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())); var currentUser = manager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()); string Address= currentUser.Address; Please advise me on what should i put on the front Master.cs code. Your help is highly appreciated –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display it on Master page you will have to add label into the HTML view of master page something like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddress"></asp:Label>
```

Here, Id of the label is important to be accessible in code behind.
Assuming you have your required data in the `Address` field of object `currentUser`.
In code behind you can use the following code to assign data from the address field to the label `lblAddress`.

```
lblAddress.Text = currentUser.Address;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i still do not know how to display the addres that belongs to the user. RIght now, my back code is like this

if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        string Address= currentUser.Address;

Please advise me on what should i put on the front Master.cs code. Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Site.Master should have the HTML code. You need to add a new label inside the <body><form runat="server"> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddress"></asp:Label>. Then come back in Site.Master.cs file and add following once you have address in string address as shown here lblAddress.Text = currentUser.Address;  Hope this helps!